# Redirecting the output to a text file in MongoDB

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu, pipe

I want to redirect the output of a mongodb command into a file, but it's not working. I searched a lot on the net, but none of the commands worked for me.

```
> mongo --quiet 99.99.99.99/db --eval 'printjson(db.productAttribute.distinct('productId'))' > /home/myname/output_query.json

Wed May 13 12:28:58.022 SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

> mongo --quiet db --eval 'printjson(db.productAttribute.distinct('productId'))' > /home/myname/output_query.json

Wed May 13 12:29:09.896 SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

The command is simple, and I don't want to put it into a separate .js file. Also, I am  trying to execute this command from the mongodb shell itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you should not run this in mongo shell. This will only work from linux shell as `mongo` executable is available in linux shell, but you are trying to call `mongo` executable from inside `mongo` shell.

Second, use double quotes in your command.

So, open a terminal window and run the following. It will work.

```
$ mongo --quiet 99.99.99.99/db --eval 'printjson(db.productAttribute.distinct("productId"))' > /home/myname/output_query.json
```